# Importing external data synchronously into a Sharepoint List

Tags: list, xml, data, csv

**Problem :**

We need external data to be imported synchronously into a Sharepoint list. The data is located in a MySQL database. The Sharepoint server is setup behind a firewall and no direct connection to the MySQL database is possible. In this situation we create a data file (XML or CSV) from the MySQL database and we want to import the data to a Sharepoint List synchronously.

How could this be done ?

I have looked into different possibilities :
-Layer2 BDLC with ODBC Conto a file
-External List / External Data Type ?
-Data Connection Library ?

Comment: I have the same problem. seems there is no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the lack of more details concerning the possibilities would work for you (e.g. looking at custom development or a no-code solution), i would the easiest is to use the BDC via SharePoint Designer to load from external source according to your schema. The major point here is what possibilities you have: could you bulk-export to some data store accessible by SharePoint, e.g. another Database? could you bulk-import your data into an SQL database?

Important is that your data store is available to SharePoint, and the BCS will transparently in real time retrieve data. External lists are actually representations of the External Content Type which you defined as Entity in your BCS.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here are more details about my possibilities : 

-I cannot use any SQL database but I can export the data I need to a file : XML or CSV. This file containing the data is then retrieved by the Sharepoint server and can be used by any mean. 

I was looking into programming a Web Service that will complete every step of the process. 1. Retrieve the file 2- Add items to the list

I will look into the BCS in more details.

I also encountered the Lists Web Service that could be useful in my situation.